# Basic explanation of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with a worked example

Tags: calculus

Looking at the fundamental theorem of calculus on Wikipedia, I can follow it until I get to the YELLOW below. I would like to find a simple worked example of the fundamental theorem of calculus with figures and formulas in it. Does anyone know of one? I find worked examples more helpful than explanations. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Since $F(0)$ is just a number, its derivative is equal to zero.

Comment: $$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(0).$$

Comment: Where did you get that explanation from? It's really bad, because it claims to generalize a calculation, but suddenly introduces a derivative that was nowhere needed in the step before. Whoever wrote that is a bad teacher.